# Creating a formula in R

Tags: r, function, variables

I am trying to create a formula which I can used to quickly check different variables for normality. I'm new to R and am not quite sure how to proceed. This is my attempt, but it does not work:

```r
normality_test <- function(my_data) { shapiro.test(my_data$"x") }
```

My goal is to be able to use the formula as follows:

```r
normality_test("variable name")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried test_normality<-function(my_data){shapiro.test(get(my_data))}, but this only works if I subsequently use test_normality(my_data$var1). I would like a function in which the normality is automatically tested for all variables in the data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[[` to access column data.

```
normality_test<- function(my_data, col) shapiro.test(my_data[[col]])
```

You can use it as :

```
normality_test(my_data, "var1")
normality_test(my_data, "var2")
```

---

To apply  `normality_test` for all the columns, you could use :

```
result <- lapply(names(my_data), normality_test, my_data = my_data)
```

However, if you want to run this for all the columns you can directly use

```
result <- lapply(my_data, shapiro.test)
```

with no need to create `normality_test` function.

Comment: Thank you! And how do I loop this formula so that it is run for all variables in the data frame?

Comment: Updated the answer to include that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working solution for you. The main difference from yours it the use of [ ] notation as opposed to $ notation for variable extraction and that mine provides both data and variable name to the function. Be sure to select only the variables which are numeric or can be coerced to such for use with the function. Also, since the function now has two arguments and the first one is data you can use `marnitrr` pipe (%>%) to make it more readable and use the function over a data set.

```
test <- mtcars
normality_test<- function(my_data, x) {     
    return(shapiro.test(as.numeric(my_data[,x])))
    }
normality_test(test, "qsec")
```

Comment: Great, it makes it a lot clearer, thank you!

Comment: @Dion Glad to help